# Mysql Export and send mail using Cron job

Tags: mysql, email, cron

I want to export select query in MYSQL and the result file needs to be send as a MAIL using Cronjob in Mysql.

Please help, Suggest a solution....
Thanks.

Comment: You should provide us first thinks what you tried before we can help you. We can not help solving your problem before you tried it

Comment: i m new in  MYSQL and i dnt know much about it. this is my requirement thats why i asked for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute queries using mysql cli. For example:

```
mysql -u 'DB_USER' -p'DB_PASS' -h 'DB_HOST' DATABASE_NAME <<< 'SELECT * FROM table_name'
```

A basic example of cron entry:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/mysql -u user -ppass -h 127.0.0.1 shop_database <<< 'SELECT * FROM customers' | mail -s 'Customers export' 'email@example.org'
```

Comment: but i didnt get mail. how to check my job is running properly or not?

Comment: You can try running the command in the terminal, before setting the cron, to see if it is working properly. Example: `mail -s subject email@example.org <<< 'test email'`. To check if the cron is running, you could add `; echo test > /home/user/cron.log` at the end of the line of the cron entry, and then check if the file `/home/user/cron.log` got created.